# PHP counter: reverse numbers in the output list

Tags: php, wordpress

I actually have a PHP loop where I'm giving to each result a number, starting from 1 and following up in ascending order. The output is as follows:

1) article C
2) article B
3) article A

...but I'd like to reverse the *list* number, so I get something like:

3) article C (article's order won't change, they are descending, by date)
2) article B
1) article A

Here's my current loop:

```
<?php
if (have_posts()) :
$counter = 1;
   while (have_posts()) :
      the_post(); ?>

    <div>
        <span class="count"><?php echo $counter; ?></span>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    </div>

<?php
$counter++;
   endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Is there an easy way to do this?
Many thanks,

Comment: Start `$counter` at the amount of posts, then do `$counter--`?

Comment: Obviously: start the counter at the highest number and count down instead of up. So the question boils down to: how to find how many posts you have? I'd start by consulting the Wordpress documentation.

Comment: If you're using HTML5, use an ordered list with the reversed attribute: <ol reversed="reversed">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [WP_Query object has a variable holding the number of posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties):

```
$query->post_count
```

So your code can become:

```
<?php
if (have_posts()) :
   global $wp_query;
   $counter = $wp_query->post_count;
   while (have_posts()) :
      the_post(); ?>

    <div>
        <span class="count"><?php echo $counter; ?></span>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    </div>

<?php
      --$counter;
   endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Fantabulous speedy answers... you're scary guys. Thanks ya'll

Comment: Uff, using `global` in 2012?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a function returning the posts count, e.g. `count_posts()` (just guessing), use it this way:

```
<?php
if (have_posts()) :
   $counter = wp_count_posts();
   while (have_posts()) :
      the_post(); ?>

    <div>
        <span class="count"><?php echo $counter; ?></span>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    </div>

<?php
$counter--;
   endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a wordpress based site/page and the function have posts relates to the wordpress function:

You might be better off with something like query_posts:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Which gives you much better control over display of the posts?

Edit:
Or alternatively if you use this:

```
$count_posts = wp_count_posts();
```

You can use this in tandem with the other answers by reversing your counter ($counter--;)

That should do the trick

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts

Comment: wp_count_posts would run a query again, so that's inefficient.